# Unity Registration: Hooking up an interface to a pre-registered concrete class

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I already have a concrete class registered in my unity container and I want to, later on, register an interface that hooks up to that class but uses the existing registration.

I can do this using the following code but it causes a resolve at registration time...

```
container.RegisterInstance<IMyClass>(container.Resolve<MyClass>());
```

Is it possible to hook the code up with all resolution done at the point the interface is resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use an `InjectionFactory`:

```
container.Register<IMyClass>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<MyClass>()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a factory type. Here, a `Func` delegate type is used to avoid the creation of a new custom factory type:

```
container.RegisterInstance<Func<IMyClass>>(() => container.Resolve<MyClass>());
```

Your other types can then take a dependency on this factory:

```
private IMyClass myClass;

public MyOtherType(Func<IMyClass> myClassFactory)
{
   this.myClass = myClassFactory();
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, it's not a factory type that I require.  I have classes which have the IMyClass interface as a constructor argument.  I want this to resolve to the (already registered) MyClass at the point the class is used rather than at the point of registration. If the concrete class wasnt preregistered and I controlled the registration, there wouldn't be a problem as I could just write the registration code for the concrete class in the RegisterType method for IMyClass.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't this approach work? i.e. when you need an instance of IMyClass you call the factory method, which does the resolution from the container at the point of the call, and will return whatever instance of IMyClass has been registered at that point?

Comment: I don't want to force anyone using this interface to use Func<IMyClass>.  If this wasn't a restriction then your suggestion would work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

var onlyInstance = new MyClass();
container.RegisterInstance<IMyClass>(onlyInstance);

IMyClass resolved = container.Resolve<IMyClass>();

if (object.ReferenceEquals(onlyInstance, resolved))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
```

This prints "Equal". This is the way I would register the instance in the first place.

In a comment above, you imply that you do not control the initial registration. That's the real issue. I would recommend going down one of the following paths (in order of preference, highest to lowest):

- Create your own UnityContainer independent of the pre-registered one
- Create a child container with CreateChildContainer
- Use named (non-default) mappings